# Flowable.zip does not work trigger all flowable but works fine seperately

Tags: rx-java

I have two Flowables and I am trying to zip them. When I subscribe them separately, them both works fine. However, when I try to zip them as followed. I only see one of them triggered. Can you please help me?

```
  Flowable.zip(Flowable1,
               Flowable2,
               BiFunction<String, CustomResult, String>
              { result1, result2 -> "result1+result2.address"})
           .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
           .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

`Flowable1` will be emit using `Flowable.create<>` with `BackpressureStrategy` while `Flowable2` its just simple `Flowable.just`, could this be an issue, if so, how can I zip them properly?

Comment: Does the zip work without subscribeOn and observeOn? How do you run it? Please show the code for flowable1.

Comment: @akarnokd flowable1 is `Flowable.create<String>({ it.onNext()}, BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER).timeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS))`

Comment: It should work. Please provide a standalone project that demonstrates your issue.